# openmpi 2.1.2 error : UCX ERROR UCP version is incompatible

Tags: openmpi

I was running `IMB-MPI1` pingpong test job with `OpenMPI 2.1.2a`. However, I got an error which says:

> UCX  ERROR UCP version is incompatible, required: 1.2, actual: 1.3 (release 0)

I didn't know what `UCX` and `UCP` is, and how should I do in order to solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UCX](http://www.openucx.org) is an abstraction layer for high performance communications, used by Infiniband among other interconnects.

You likely upgraded this library without Open MPI knowing it.

The first step would be to rebuild Open MPI from the sources.

Comment: @Giles    Yes, the problem has gone after recompile Open MPI from the soruces.  Many Thanks!